# Generalization of matching problem for knives and forks

Tags: probability, combinations

Inspired by [Probability of knives and forks matching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664689/probability-of-knives-and-forks-matching/3664711), the following problem occurs to me:

Assume we have $3n$ knives and $3n$ forks, of which $n$ knives and forks are red, $n$ knives and forks are black, and $n$ knives and forks are white.

Now assume the knives and forks are randomly paired with one another.  What is the probability that no knife is paired with a fork of the same color?

Note that for $n=1, 2$, the probability is $\frac{1}{3^n}$.  (I provided the answer to the $n=2$ case in the linked question.)  Is that the general answer?  If there are $k$ colors instead of $3$ colors, is the answer for the analogous problem $\frac{1}{k^n}$?

Comment: For $3$ colours and $3$ of each colour, the probability seems to be $\frac{1}{30}$ so the answer seems to be no

Comment: And for $k=2$ colours the number seems to be $1/{2n \choose n}$ rather than $1/2^n$

Comment: @Henry  That appears to answer my conjecture about the general form of the answer.  I'm still curious whether the question has an answer with an interesting general form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting that the probability is $$\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!} \cdot \sum_{a = 0}^n \binom{n}a^3.$$

Let $I_1 = 1 \cdots n, I_2 = n+1 \cdots 2n, I_3= 2n+1 \cdots 3n$. We can think of the desired matching as a permutation $f$ on $3n$ elements such that $f$ satisfies the following: $f$ applied to $I_j$ avoids $I_j$ for all $j$.

To construct such a $f$, we first specify the values that it takes for $I_1$. The number of ways to pick integers for these values is $\binom{n}a \binom{n}{n-a}$ for some $a \ge 0$ since we need to pick $a$ integers from $n+1$ to $2n$ and $n-a$ from $2n+1$ to $3n$.

Now this means that all the left over integers from $2n+1$ to $3n$ that we didn't pick as the image of some element in $I_1$ must be the image of some element in $I_2$. There are $a$ such left over integers. Then we need to pick $n-a$ integers from $1$ to $n$ since the range of $f$ applied $I_2$ needs $n$ integers. This completely determines the range for $f$ applied to $I_3$.

Finally, for each $I_j$, we can permute the values that they are mapped to and still satisfy our desired condition. There are $(n!)^3$ such ways to do this. Dividing by the total number of permutations gives us the probability.

The generalization to $k$ buckets is clear but we instead get multinomial sums. Hopefully some nice asymptotic is possible.

Comment: I'm not following why your buckets provide combinations in $1-1$ correspondence with "good" permutations.  Would you mind elaborating?  Thanks.

Comment: Lets say the first n knives are red, the second n are black and the last n are white. Then a matching of the knives and fork is the same as a function f from 1...3n to 1...3n that has the property that  f applied to first n integers avoids the first n integers, f applied to n+1 to 2n avoids n+1 to 2n and so on. To build f, we just need to specify where each integer is mapped to. To do this, we can first figure out where 1 to n is mapped to, where n+1 to 2n is mapped to, and where 2n+1 to 3n is mapped to. These are the three buckets.

Comment: Continued: The buckets represent the possible ranges of f applied to 1 to n, f applied to n+1 to 2n, and f applied to 2n+1 to 3n. Then since the ranges dont matter (for instance, f(1) and f(2) can be switched and the restriction that we want still holds), we permute the bucket values to get all possible permutations. Since each bucket has n items, it means (n!)^3 total ways to get all valid permutation from a given choice of buckets. Then we multiply by the total possible different buckets.

Comment: May I ask that you incorporate this reasoning into the answer?  Also, It's useful to simplify the answer by noting that $\binom{n}{a}=\binom{n}{n-a}$.

Comment: sure, i edited my answer